# Event study renders treatment effect significant

Tags: statistical-significance, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, generalized-did

Currently, I am working with crime panel data (county-day level over several years) to investigate the effect of police presence on crime. I use an "exogenous" increase in police presence for one day every year to account for endogeneity bias and apply a two-way fixed effects model to account for unobserved heterogeneity (county fixed effects, as well as year, month, and day-of-week fixed effects). Therefore, my main regression is stated as:

$$
C_{ct} = \beta_1 Police_{ct} + _c +year + month +day + \beta_2 X_{ct} + \epsilon_{ct}. 
$$

The treatment indicator "Police" is equal to 1 if police presence is increased in county $c$ at day $t$, and zero otherwise. Running this regression with interacted fixed effects gives statistically insignificant results (p-values ~ 0.06). See first table (standard errors in parentheses).

However, when I check the parallel trends assumption and include 5 lags and 4 leads the treatment "Police" is statistically significant (p-value ~ 0.04). See second table (standard errors in parentheses).

[image: Results from the main regression]

[image: Event Study]

Has anyone had a similar problem and can help me out?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome. First, do you really get estimates for all of the year and month effects? Second, when you say "interacted" fixed effects, what do you mean exactly? Do you mean you're interacting $Police_{ct}$ with the fixed effects? Given your definition of the treatment variable, you don't necessarily need to do this. And third, when you say $Police_{ct}$ is significant with when you include the leads and lags, which of those is significantly exactly? The first lag?

Comment: Hello @ThomasBilach , it is a pleasure to meet you. I have already read your comments on statalist and your crime paper. With "interacting" fixed effects, I meant to interact the county fixed effect with the time fixed effects. Actually, no lag or lead is significantly. The only coefficient that is significant (p-value < 0.05) in the Event Study is Police (treatment indicator). But in my main regression (see above) the p-value of Police is larger than 0.05. And this result confuses me. How can the stat. sign. level change when using lags and leads?

Comment: Thank you for reading the paper. In standard econometrics jargon, the "leads" and/or "lags" usually mean we have substituted different time configurations of $Police_{ct}$ into the model. For example, something like $Police_{c, t-1}$. So what you're saying is the *immediate* effect is significant, but not so much as we move farther away from that first day of the increased police presence? I just want to make sure we agree on our terminology.

Comment: I edited my post and provided the results for the main regression and the event study. The red marked coefficients (immediate effect) are identical, meaning both are equal to 1 if police presence is increased in county c at day t, and zero otherwise. Therefore, they shouldn´t be different in size, when including leads and lags, but they are. To sum it up why does the coefficient size of Police (or lag0) change if leads and lags are included? Does this help you understanding my confusion?

Comment: The red marked coefficients (immediate effect) are identical *constructed

Comment: And technically the immediate effect is the same day across specifications because the surge in police presence is a one day shock every year. Is this correct? Also, that would mean the treatment variable is switching back and forth between 0 and 1 *multiple times* over time—within treated counties. Is this correct as well?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I just saw that the number of observations considered in the event study is smaller than in the main regression. Somehow observations get dropped when running the event study. I´ll check on that.

Comment: I think the problem is autocorrelation since I have not clustered the standard errors.  Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 3):

Before answering your question, I want to discuss the fixed effects. For instance, your model includes year, month, and day-of-the-week fixed effects. This leaves me with more questions than answers. You should be very clear about what these effects mean and why you're estimating them. I will address each concern, in turn.

First, since you're estimating a two-way fixed effects equation with a policy that "turns on" (i.e., switches from 0 to 1) and also "turns off" (i.e., switches from 1 back to 0) at the **day level**, then your model must include county and day fixed effects. To be clear, a true "day" fixed effect accounts for the full number of days a unit is observed; it should **not** be a repeating sequence within a panel unit. Including day-of-the-week fixed effects, alone, does not meet the basic requirements for a different-in-differences specification. At a minimum, you must include county and day fixed effects.

In your setting, for example, estimating day-of-the-week fixed effects is saying there is some temporal shock in your crime outcome experienced by all counties—every Tuesday (or Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, etc.); again, that's every Tuesday regardless of the month or year, or even the state or region within which the county is located. This is not the "time" fixed effects that are required in a typical difference-in-differences equation. The "day" fixed effects represent a series of day-specific shocks common to each county. In other words, the time (day) fixed effects would distinguish between, say, the second Tuesday in April of 2016 in Kings County New York and the second Tuesday in April of 2017 in Kings County New York. There are many unique ways of creating a "day" variable so it distinguishes between all of the county-day pairs. For example, if you have a date variable (e.g., `"2018-04-01", "2018-04-02", "2018-04-03"`, etc.), then that should work just fine. Another approach is to define an integer sequence that accounts for each day across all years. Note, again, that the day fixed effects adjust for those common *daily* shocks affecting all counties. If we observe counties over 4 years (48 months), then we're estimating 1,460 separate day effects. In short, a repeating day-of-the-week variable (i.e., 1–7) isn't going to cut it. At the most basic level, two-way fixed effects implies separate county and day fixed effects. Since the increase in police presence over time has daily level variation, then day fixed effects is the way to go.

If, however, the shocks affect **all counties** (everywhere), as your comments have suggested, then day fixed effects may be redundant with the policy *within a year*. But introducing day-of-the-week fixed effects may fix one problem at the expense of another. In the comments you ask:

> Controlling for every day would eliminate the treatment effect of those treatment days, right?

Correct, but only if $Police_{ct} = 1$ for all counties *on the same day* within a year. Note that adjusting for the days of the week eliminates a policy variable introduced to all counties on the same day too. For example, if the surge in police presence is the fourth Wednesday in June in *all counties*, then how would we distinguish the policy variable from the day-of-the-week fixed effects? The treatment variable is switching from 0 to 1 on the fourth Wednesday of June in all counties, everywhere; that's one single day where every county experiences a shock. Introducing a dummy variable for a day of the week would equal 1 on every Wednesday in every month, in every year, in all counties, everywhere; that's adjusting for a recurring shock on Wednesday, where on one of those Wednesdays there is a major surge in police presence, everywhere. Do you see a similar problem? Again, the day-of-the-week fixed effects models the *recurring* shocks that repeat weekly in every area, while the day fixed effects adjust for those temporal shocks shared by all counties across the board but vary from one day to the next.

Introducing day fixed effects is not a problem if, across years, we have some counties experiencing a surge in police presence, and some do not. It may be the case that in one slice of time, all counties saw an increased police presence. But this isn't the case over the years. In fact, in some years there is more guardianship while it others there is not. We can turn to the "non-adopter" counties, within *and* across years, to help us approximate the counterfactual. Note that the difference-in-differences estimator is a weighted average of the smaller two-by-two estimates within, and across, the different county-years. In one (or some) of those years, however, the increased exposure of the police over the population is deterministic; we know it affects everyone at the same time and in the say. If you're publishing these findings, I would recommend producing a treatment variation plot so readers can see how the pulsating treatment varies over the county-day-month-years.

Now for my second concern. You can't estimate year, month, *and* day fixed effects simultaneously. Did you try estimating the year *and* month fixed effects directly? Depending upon the software, or even the order in which you estimate the different time effects, some of them will end up getting dropped. This isn't to say you can't account for seasonality in other ways. For example, to test the robustness of your findings, estimating county-by-quarter effects (repeating quarters) or county-by-month effects (repeating monthly interval) seems appropriate. In the former setting, maybe you want to account for some common shock experienced by all counties in, say, the second quarter of each year. You might also suspect temporal shocks to vary by state as well. In the end, just be very, very clear about what these fixed effects actually mean.

Lastly, you cannot estimate a series of county-day effects (i.e., unit $\times$ time) with a county-day panel. This would only chew up all your degrees of freedom. I suspect the unit-time interactions didn't fail in practice because you multiplied the county identifier by month, or year. The county-day interactions would completely eliminate the county-day policy variable variable(s), so be careful.

Hopefully that provided further clarity.

> Running this regression with interacted fixed effects gives statistically insignificant results (p-values ~ 0.06). See first table (standard errors in parentheses).

As noted earlier, I don't know what "interacted" fixed effects means in your setting, but if it's county-day interactions, then this isn't possible, unless you have district/precinct level data at some lower level. If it's county-year or county-quarter interactions, then that seems okay, so long as you outline why it's important to adjust for those particular effects.

As for the "significance" of the findings. I wouldn't obsess over it. First, I would urge you to address the practical importance of the findings. What does $-0.023$ represent? What's on the left-hand side of your equation? The logged *daily* crime rate? Is it a 2% reduction in violent crime? Given your threshold, the estimate reported in column (3) is not significantly bounded away from zero. But is this result any more (or less) interesting (important) whether $p = 0.06$ or $ p = 0.04$? I would have expected stronger evidence of a crime suppression effect with such a very, very large panel (i.e., $N \times T \approx 426,000$).

> However, when I check the parallel trends assumption and include 5 lags and 4 leads the treatment "Police" is statistically significant (p-value ~ 0.04).

I really hope the "leads" represent the periods after the *immediate effect* of increased police. By the definition of $Police_{ct}$, it follows that $Police_{c,t + 1}$ is the effect of police withdrawal. If so, the coefficient suggests a residual deterrent effect. Perhaps there's a persistent influence of the shock, beyond the immediate effect of more police, that's ignored using just a static model. Once you account for the persistence, then the effect of the immediate increase in police presence is more pronounced.

> Has anyone had a similar problem and can help me out?

I wouldn't say you have a problem.

You should *not* be surprised to see the coefficient on $Police_{ct}$ change when you include covariates. On the one hand, if a surge in police presence is not so exogenous (it usually isn't), then the lags do absorb some of the shocks in the pre-policy period. On the other hand, if we suspect the "signal" of more visible police persists even beyond the one day, then modeling the withdrawal day(s) directly may actually be more appropriate. This is one the advantages of the event study model over the static specification.

Estimates may also vary depending upon the length of the effect window, or which day(s) is used as the reference period. Moreover, as you include more and more leads/lags, you're also losing more observations. Some of the leads/lags may be collinear with the other fixed effects, but it's hard to tell given how many different versions of time you've entered into the model.

---

Here are my suggestions: (1) Include day fixed effects. The most spartan model, given the variation in your treatment variable, should include county *and* day fixed effects; start there, then try more complicated stuff such as estimating county-by-quarter or region-by-day fixed effects; clearly outline why you're doing this. (2) Define a lead/lag structure and stick with it; do not estimate endless strings of models. Do not expect the coefficient on the policy variable to stay the same in each setting. (3) Cluster your standard errors. Your tabular results suggest you're using "robust" standard errors? Robust to what? Heteroskedasticity? In my most humble opinion, please cluster your standard errors; cluster at the level of treatment administration, which is probably state.

---

**See comments**

I'm going to extend my answer a bit. The comments suggest you also have state level variation. In other words, you have a very large number of counties nested within a few states. What's still confusing to me is whether this is truly a state level initiative. I would assume if a state doesn't adopt the policy, then all of the county-day pairs *within* states don't experience the 1-day increase in police presence.

If this is truly some state level intervention, then it *should* affect all counties *within* those states, but it doesn't necessarily have to. You could very well have a state level policy and variation down at the county level as well. Maybe legislators at the state level gave some counties more money to tackle a particular crime problem but not others. Maybe some municipalities already had the staffing to increase police presence during specific high-profile events. Even at this lower level, it appears you have some unique switching "on" and "off" of treatment over the years within states. Because of the nested structure, I am going to recommend another specification. You don't have to incorporate it, but I'd be very concerned about other state level policies that were introduced in specific years that might also affect crime rates.

Here is another specification worth pursuing and shares some of the characteristics of difference-in-differences:

$$
crime_{ct} = \delta police_{ct} + \beta X_{ct} + \alpha_c + \eta_{(s)t} + \epsilon_{ct}
$$

The basic structure is the same, but now we introduce $\eta_{(s)t}$, a state-day fixed effect. This is more aptly considered a state-day-month-year fixed effect since you have more granular times series data. In a simple setting with a county-year panel, this is similar to estimating a series of state-year interactions; we multiply states with **all years**. Since you have a daily observations, then we interact states with **all days**. Put differently, the $s$ and $t$ subscripts imply state $\times$ day interactions, since we must distinguish between all the days across the month-years. Sometimes we concatenate units (states) and times (days) and call it a state-day-month-year fixed effect; it's a mouthful to say, but you get the idea. In this sense, you're restricting counterfactual time trends to those counties nested within the same state. You may find it important to capture those trends common to all counties *within the same state* during the same day-month-year. Given that your observations are sub-regional (sub-state), then you'll end up with more robust estimates by putting in all these interactions. Some may argue it's a little too demanding in your setting, but it's worth the try.

Clustering on county isn't fatal in my opinion. We need some way to account for the dependence among observations over time within a county. Clustering on state is problematic since you're only working with a small number of clusters. Maybe you should consider 'unit-time' clustering. You should suspect some dispersion and dependence common to state *and* time. I'm a little hesitant to advise you on this matter given the scanty number of states. If you know other states didn't see their counties increase police presence on those specific days, then I'd try getting access to the county level crime rates for the counties within those states.

In my field, I've seen 'unit-time' clustering used at a more local level. For example, [MacDonald and colleagues (2016)](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0157223) published a paper in PLOS One investigating the effects of a crime policy implemented at the precinct level. The dataset consists of over 8,000 block groups, nested within 76 precincts, nested within 5 counties. The increased police presence is all down at the block group level, but the "precinct" really determines "where" the police will go. They observe each block group $i$ over a long series of month-years $t$. With granular data at a level lower than the precinct, they clustered on "precinct-month-year" to allow for dispersion and dependence common to the precinct *and* time. Again, this paper might not be of interest to you, but it shows where this sort of high dimensional unit-time clustering is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! (1) I apologise for the lack of precision in the description of variables and treatment setting. Treatment does not vary between counties in all years. That means for some years all counties participate at the same day and consequently no county-level variation can be exploited. This motivated me to use year-, month-of-year and day-of-week fixed effects. Imagine a treatment on 13.04.2015 (= Wednesday) that occurs for all counties.

Comment: Following my approach the estimation would compare the crime rates of the treated Wednesday to all other Wednesdays in all other months in all other years. Therefore, month and year specific crime rates must be removed to compare apples with apples. Controlling for every day would eliminate the treatment effect of those treatment days, right? (2) Thank you, I will do that.

Comment: (3) Those standard errors are robust to heteroskedasticity. Treatment is assigned at state level, therefor the standard errors should be clustered at state level. However, this would result in three clusters and therefore would lead to other problems. Cluster at the county level would "only" account for correlation over time within one county. I thought about using county-level clusters as a baseline and run the regression again with bootstrapped standard errors.

Comment: We need to sort this out. (1) So all counties experience this surge in cops on the same day? I’m under the impression that in some years, there are some counties that do *not* increase the number of cops. In short, we need a subset of control counties. That ties into my next concern. (2) Do you only observe counties within 3 states? If so, for those states that do not introduce the policy, it would imply no increase in the country-day pairs *within* those states, correct? Why do some states increase and some don’t? What sort of cross-sectional variation do you have here?

Comment: Setting: 3 states, 166 counties. Once in a year a nationwide traffic monitoring campaign is systematically implemented. On this day police presence is increased to detect traffic violations. Theoretically the exogenous increase in police presence at these days should also deter other crimes beyond traffic violations. However, participation is not mandatory and therefore in 4 out of 8 years only 2 of the 3 states participated (~100 counties are treated, 66 not), whereas in the other half all three states participated.

Comment: For the years when all states (166 counties) participate, the two-way fixed effects regression compares the "treatment" Wednesday against the average Wednesday in the corresponding county within state s (no treatment variation between states). In the years when only two states participate, the TW FE regression compares the "treatment" Wednesday with both the average Wednesday in the same county in state s and the average Wednesday in the control state (treatment variation between states). Or is my understanding mistaken here?

Comment: I updated my answer. As for your interpretation of the day-of-the-week fixed effects, this seems appropriate. But be careful, because in some years, all counties *everywhere* increase their police presence for one day. If this is a Wednesday in all counties *everywhere* in 2015, then how would we distinguish this discrete treatment experienced *everywhere* from the repeating Wednesday shocks? To be clear, I'm not saying this completely eliminates the treatment variable(s), but it will be redundant with the time shocks in some of the years (not all years). Does this make sense?